# Programatically close an expanded row with a button

Tags: angular

I've used this model to create a table with expanded rows :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sorting?file=app%2Fcdk-detail-row.directive.ts

Problem is that I cannot get a row to expand or close without clicking on it.

For example :

When I click on row, it expands in the ng-template :

```
<ng-template #tpl let-element>
    <div class="mat-row detail-row" [@detailExpand] style="overflow: hidden">
       <button type="button" (click)="closeRow()">Close Row</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I'd like to be able to close that row by clicking on the button inside the ng-template.

Hope this is not too confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved and you can try it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-expandable-rows-filter-pagination-sort-7jpsik?file=app%2Ftable-example.ts

What was changed:

**cdk-detail-row.directive.ts**

adding emmitter

31:   `@Output() toggleChange = new EventEmitter<CdkDetailRowDirective>(); // added`

emitting on toggle

47:   `this.toggleChange.emit(this); // added`

**table-example.html**

binding toggle

39:   `(toggleChange)="onToggleChange($event)"`

adding button to close row on click

48:   `<button type="button" (click)="closeRow()">Close Row</button>`

**table-example.ts**

adding variable to track what row is expanded

30:   `private openedRow: CdkDetailRowDirective`

managing `cdkDetailRow.expended`

43-52:

```
  onToggleChange(cdkDetailRow: CdkDetailRowDirective) : void {
    if (this.openedRow && this.openedRow.expended) {
      this.openedRow.toggle();      
    }
    this.openedRow = cdkDetailRow.expended ? cdkDetailRow : undefined;
  }

  closeRow() {
    this.onToggleChange(this.openedRow);
  }
```

Comment: I made it work thanks to you! Thank you so much, you really helped me out there!

Comment: How can you expand for example only on button? For example disable expand when click on the row?